# Compare two version of zip file and find which file has been modified within that zip

Tags: bash, command-line

I have two zip files called 10.88.10 and 10.88.12. One or more files in 10.88.12 have been modified. Is there any way I can find out which file has been modified?

The zip file contains a directory, a subdirectory, and zip files inside.

Code I've tried (I don't think I am on right path):

```
m1= md5sum 10.88.10.zip | cut -d' ' -f1
m2=  md5sum 10.88.12.zip | cut -d' ' -f1

 if [ "m1" != "m2" ]; then
                echo file are not same


cd "/c/Users/name/Downloads/10.88.10/"

while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]
do

        cd "/c/Users/name/Downloads/10.88.10/"
        find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;
done

cd "/c/Users/name/Downloads/10.88.12/"


        while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]
        do
                find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;
        done

cd "/c/Users/name/Downloads/"
        find 10.88.10/* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum |cut -d' ' -f1 > file1.txt
        find 10.88.12/* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum | cut -d' ' -f1 > file2.txt
       diff file1.txt file2.txt


else
        echo false
fi
```

I tried hash to find out modified file by comparing and getting unique values but unfortunately I only receive the hash and can't think of a way to get names of the the input file which corresponds to that hash.

Running the hash cmd:

```
find 10.88.10/* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum
```

Output:

```
c3f2b563b3cb091e2adsss321221a3d *10.88.12/name.xml
```

Difference/Modified file in hash:

```
1c1
< 3c2a991d1231c3eae391fadsdadda19e8f7b85df8caf2d
---
> c3f2b56qwdq2112e375b40fbfd5e60f526da3d1874c1874
< fbdc82dasdaa30538e5adadadada2d9456ff86953fbeeb1
---
> f962e8eqeqeqqe3b65d3ed43559adc879f5600c738e1e1c
```

Required output:

```
 < 10.88.10/FOLDER/FILE1.XML 
---
> 10.88.12/FOLDER1/FILE1.XML
< 10.88.10/FOLDER/FILE2.TXT
---
> 10.88.12/FOLDER/FILE2.TXT
```

IF anyone has a Java solution or bash script please share it.

Comment: Are all the filenames in the two archives the same? So you're just looking for cases where the file contents changed, not added or deleted files?

Comment: Most of the files would be same because 10.88.10(zip 1 is a version 1 file) . 10.88.12(zip 2 would be the updated version of 10.88.10. so there might be a delete and extra added file) So i need to find them files too. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a shell script that leverages the sqlite3 command line tool's [ability to open zip files](https://sqlite.org/zipfile.html) to avoid having to unzip the files into a temporary location and using some simple SQL to do all the work:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

oldfile="$1"
newfile="$2"

sqlite3 -batch -bail <<EOF
.mode tabs
.headers off
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE oldfile USING zipfile('${oldfile}');
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE newfile USING zipfile('${newfile}');
-- Show files present in newfile that are absent in oldfile
SELECT 'added', name
FROM (SELECT name FROM newfile EXCEPT SELECT name FROM oldfile)
ORDER BY name;
-- Show files missing from newfile that are present in oldfile
SELECT 'deleted', name
FROM (SELECT name FROM oldfile EXCEPT SELECT name FROM newfile)
ORDER BY name;
-- Show files whose contents differ between the two
SELECT 'modified', of.name
FROM oldfile AS of
JOIN newfile AS nf ON of.name = nf.name
WHERE of.data <> nf.data
ORDER BY of.name;
EOF
```

Example usage:

```
$ unzip -l test1.zip
Archive:  test1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2020-02-27 04:05   1/
        4  2020-02-27 04:05   1/a.txt
        4  2020-02-27 04:05   1/b.txt
        4  2020-02-27 04:05   a.txt
---------                     -------
       12                     4 files
$ unzip -l test2.zip
Archive:  test2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2020-02-27 04:07   1/
        4  2020-02-27 04:07   1/a.txt
        4  2020-02-27 04:06   a.txt
        4  2020-02-27 04:06   b.txt
---------                     -------
       12                     4 files
$ ./cmpzip test1.zip test2.zip
added   b.txt
deleted 1/b.txt
modified        1/a.txt
```

(I'm not sure why you want diff-style output when all you seem to care about is *if* a file changed, not *what* the change is, so this produces TSV output that's easier to understand and work with in further processing)

Comment: Thanks Shawn for taking your time. I ran the code and it outputted me with an error saying sqlite3 command not found. It probably because of sqlite3 not being installed on desktop ? . Is there any alternative way to fix this. I cant install sqlite3 on the college pc due to not having admin permission.

Comment: @X00145570 interesting. I thought it came out of the box on pretty much every common os these days. There are precompiled binaries for linux and a few other oses available on the sqlite site iirc.

Comment: i rechecked in program files and there is a file called sqllite3.0.*  Do you know what might the cause of error : "line 4: sqlite3: command not found".

Comment: 3.25.3 precise version